# How to resolve ambiguous key sequence?

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde

Using BasKet, I get the following message:

> **Ambiguous Shortcut Detected**
>   The key sequence 'Ctrl+1' is ambiguous. Use 'Configure Shortcuts'
>   from the 'Settings' menu to solve the ambiguity.
>   No action will be triggered.

'Ctrl+1' is shown next to 'To-Do' under the 'Tags' menu. If I look in 'Configure Shortcuts' I don't find Ctrl+1 assigned to anything (the tag shortcuts aren't listed at all, leading me to believe their assignment is hard coded). I looked under 'System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts' and also searched through CompizConfig, but didn't find anything there that might conflict.

How do I resolve this keyboard shortcut issue?

I'm guessing the particular program or key sequence isn't too important. It looks like it happens with a number of KDE programs (sadly I haven't seen a solution).

Comment: If you unset Ctrl+1, what does it trigger then?

Comment: Interesting. I unset it through Tags > Customize > Shortcut, and Ctrl+1 did nothing. I set it back to Ctrl+1 and now it works! Ctrl+1 triggers both toggling the checkbox on, and checking it. So maybe there is a bug with resolving a shortcut with multiple actions. Ctrl+2 has the same problem.

Comment: Sadly the above appears not to have solved it. Just started basket and all shortcuts but one were working. I tried to fix it as with Ctrl+1 and now they're all broken again.

Answer (score 2):

"Ok, this is mainly about spit view: If you start kate and splitted views are restored, you always get that. If you click in all views once, all works fine again."

There is more information in https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=188764

The bug was fixed in 2011